# How to call column name started with the number with Active Record Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If column name in DB named `2way` in `posts` table,

```
post = Post.first
post.2way
```

occurred:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected tINTEGER, expecting '(
post.2way
      ^
```

Tried `Post.'2way'` still not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you:

```
Post.last.send("2way")

Post.all.pluck("2way") #this will work if your column name in your migration file defined as a string in quotes, for example, t.integer '2way'
```

If you want to set a value:
`post.public_send('2way=', value)`

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: If I want to set a value to it, this not work: `post.send('2way') = 1`.

Comment: Don't use `send`, there is `write_attribute`. If you encourage `send` at least use `public_send`.

Comment: @FaZeUnempl0yedd Why don't use `send`?

Comment: @02040402 because `send` also has access to private and protected methods. Another problem with both `send` and `public_send` is that it will make your app easily exploitable, if you'd have a dynamic attribute write like `object.public_send(dangerous_user_input, user_provided_value)`. The latter is not the case here, just also worth pointing out.

Comment: @FaZeUnempl0yedd Another question, how can update it? `post.public_send('2way=', 1)` seems not update already saved value.

Answer (score 1):

Column name cannot start with a number. So when you are defining  your migration, you can do it as:

```
t.integer '2way'
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: You need to call `post.send('2way')` after defining in migration to fetch value.

Answer (score 1):

As NN796 said, you can set the value with the `public_send` method:

```rb
post.public_send('2way=', value)
```

Comment: How to update the exist value? This one is used for first saving? I fount the value didn't change at the second time.

Answer (score 0):

you can try in this way:

```
post.try(:2way)
```